# PHP Symfony: How to access a getter-Constraint in a form template?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I created a simple entity-class that holds some properties and a public getter-Method that executes some stuff and returns true or false.

```
class Item {
    public prop1;
    public prop2;

    public function isGetterConstraint() {
        return true // or false based on some calculations
    }
}
```

Then I defined the constraints for that class in the validation.yml:

```
Foo\MyBundle\Entity\Item:
    properties:
        prop1:
            - NotBlank: ~
        prop2:
            - NotBlank: ~
    getters:
        getterConstraint:
            - "True": { message: "zu" }
```

That's what you see in many examples, but I have not found out how to access this getter-constraint in a form either within the controller or the twig template. In my case I do need it within the template.

If I define my FormType like that

```
class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('prop1', 'text')
            ->add('prop2', 'text');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'item';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Foo\MyBundle\Entity\Item',
        ));
    }
}
```

and my Controller like that

```
class ItemController extends Controller {
    public function createAction(Request $request) {
        $item = new Item();

        $form = $this->buildForm($item);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // do some nice things like saving the data
        }
        return $this->render('FooMyBundle:Item:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
}
```

the form does not know about the getter-constraint and I can't access it like I'm used to with property constraints:

```
// form.html.thwig

{% if form.prop1.vars.errors %}{% endif %} // works

{% if form.getterConstraint.vars.errors %}{% endif %} // doesnot work
```

Is there a way to add the getter constraint to the FormType or what do I have to do to make the form consider this constraint when validating the data and expose the result to the controller or template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the getter constraint direct in your entity

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Entity/Author.php

// ...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\True;

class Author
{
    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addGetterConstraint('passwordLegal', new True(array(
            'message' => 'The password cannot match your first name',
        )));
    }
public function isPasswordLegal()
{
    return $this->firstName != $this->password;
}
}
```

Demo code taken from [**Symfony Validation**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)

Or you can define the callbacks in your entity with annotations

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Entity/Author.php

// ...

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isPasswordLegal"})
 */
class Author
{
public function isPasswordLegal(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    $context->addViolationAt('password', 'wrong password');
}  
}
```

And in controller you can do so

```
// src/KnpU/QADayBundle/Controller/EventController.php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;
use KnpU\QADayBundle\Entity\Event;
// ...
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, array(
        'data_class' => 'KnpU\QADayBundle\Entity\Event',
        'constraints' => array(
            new Assert\Callback(array(array($this, 'validateEventDates')))
        )
    ))
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('startDate', 'datetime')
        ->add('endDate', 'datetime')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    // ...
}

public function validateEventDates(Event $event, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    $context->addViolationAt('startDate', 'There is already an event during this time!');
}
```

[**Custom Validation, Callback and Constraints**](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path)